# QlikView: Iris clustering using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, analytics, qlikview

I am working on a QlikView project using R for advanced analytics tasks.
The example comes from https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-18787 and consists in reading data from the famous Iris database and classify each flower according to its petal and sepal dimensions.

In particular, I want to load flower data in the Script, and then send the columns that I've loaded to R, to calculate, for each record, the cluster it belongs to.

```
IrisLoad:
LOAD observation, 
     [sepal length] as sepLen, 
     [sepal width] as sepWid, 
     [petal length] as petLen, 
     [petal width] as petWid, 
     [iris species]
FROM
Data\Iris.csv
(txt, codepage is 1252, embedded labels, delimiter is ',', msq);

SSELoad:
Load 
    observation,
    R.ScriptEval('kmeans(cbind(q$petLen, q$petWid, q$sepLen, q$sepWid), 3, nstart=20)$cluster', petLen, petWid, sepLen, sepWid) as IrisCluster                           
Resident IrisLoad;
```

The thing is that I want to send to R the whole columns sepLen, sep Wid, petLen, petWid, and **not one record per time**, which is what happens with SSELoad.
My intention with SSELoad is to get 2 columns, one representing the observations, and one which correponds to their clustering group, based on the calculations made on the **whole** columns sepLen, sep Wid, petLen, petWid previously retrieved from the csv file.

Can anybody give me a hint on how could I implement it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason to want to use the R integration during data load? Qlik's AAI (Advanced Analytics Integration) is more suitable to be used "on the fly"  - inside chart expression. This way all data (based on the selections ofc) is send to R

Comment: Well, my idea of using the script was to have a new "variable" containing the information about each observation's cluster. A variable which is general, and visible in every part of the program, not just inside a single chart. But actually now I am realizing this is not the best option. The original intention with this example program was to create a scatter chart of the observations, with petal width and length as x/y axes, and colors based on the cluster. But also in this case, it seems like Qlikview passes data to R one point at a time, which prevents R from grouping data into 3 clusters.

Comment: Why would you use qlik at all and not just real R?

Comment: Because I want to integrate these Advanced Analytics functions on a pre existing Qlikview project.